# what is the password for virtual box images found here https://rosi-images.datasys.swri.edu/

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what is the password for virtual box images found here https://rosi-images.datasys.swri.edu/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375308/what-is-the-password-for-virtual-box-images-found-here-https://rosi-images.datasys.swri.edu//) by [0xdoggie](https://answers.ros.org/users/72849/0xdoggie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-04-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [0xdoggie](https://answers.ros.org/users/72849/0xdoggie/) on 2021-04-03**:
guys i need this fast . please approve

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-03**:\

> guys i need this fast . please approve

there is no point in posting comments like this.

They won't show up any sooner/higher in the moderation queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is clearly stated in [the documentation](https://industrial-training-master.readthedocs.io/en/melodic/_source/setup/PC-Setup---ROS.html#virtual-machine-configuration-recommended):

> #### Virtual Machine Configuration (Recommended)
>
> The VM method is the most convenient method of utilizing the training materials:
>
> [..]
>
> 5. Log into virtual machine, user: `ros-industrial`, pass: `rosindustrial` (no spaces or hyphens)

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [0xdoggie](https://answers.ros.org/users/72849/0xdoggie/) on 2021-04-03**:
Thanks man..